# React: UI Flickering When State Updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-hooks

I have a component that displays search data returned from the Spotify API. However, every time I update the state the UI flickers:

[image]
Input:

```
            <DebounceInput
                debounceTimeout={300}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
```

Hook:

```
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState(null)
```

API call w/ Apollo:

```
 const searchSpotify = async (query) => {
    const result = await props.client.query({
        query: SearchTracks,
        variables: {
            query
        }
    })
    const tracks = result.data.searchedTracks
    setSearchResults(tracks)
}
```

Render:

```
        {searchResults &&
            <div className="search-results">
                    {searchResults.map((song) => (
                            <SongInfo key={song.id} {...song} />
                    ))}
            </div>
        }
```

I noticed it only happens on the first load. For example, if I were to type the query again it shows without flickering. Is there a better way to implement this so the UI doesn't flicker?

Comment: You could add a loading state where when you make the api call to fetch you toggle a loading flag/state.

Comment: Have you tried adding `key` prop to your `SongInfo` element? Something like, `<SongInfo key={song.id} {...song} />` (change id to whatever property uniquely identifies your song). Adding key prop to list items improves React performance.

Comment: @varoons The loading state happens so quickly that it actually makes the UI worse

Comment: @abadalyan I have a key in my actual code, I tried simplifying it for this question. I edited the <SongInfo> component to clarify

Comment: If you replace SongInfo with simple <div>{song.name}</div> does it flicker?

Comment: Is there `useEffect` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Powell_v2 There is not. I've been reading guides on it all day but I don't understand how to use it in this scenario.

Comment: @abadalyan It doesn't appear to flicker when it's just text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below are the frames that cause the flicker. What I think is happening is it takes some time for the images to load. While they are loading the items have reduced height. You should make sure `SongInfo` layout does not depend on whether the image has been loaded or not.

Images not loaded - items are collapsed:

[image]

Images were loaded:

[image]

Comment: You're right, it's definitely an issue with the <img src={song.imageUrl}> part of <SongInfo>. I set a default height and width and that seems to help but the image itself seems to be flickering as it's loading/rendering. I'm looking into it now.

Answer (score 5):

I think whats happening is that you are executing a search query on every key stroke which is causing the weird behavior.

Use lodash debounce to avoid doing a search on every key stroke.
That should address the flickering. (Also, adding a loading state will help)

Sample debounce component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

class TableSearch extends Component {

  //********************************************/

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        value: props.value
    }

    this.changeSearch = debounce(this.props.changeSearch, 250)
  }

  //********************************************/

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const val = e.target.value

    this.setState({ value: val }, () => {
      this.changeSearch(val)
    })
  }

  //********************************************/

  render() {

    return (
        <input
            onChange = {this.handleChange}
            value = {this.props.value}
        />
    )
  }

  //********************************************/

}
```

Comment: I'm actually using a [DebounceInput](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-debounce-input). It did help but it still isn't ideal. I edited the question to clarify.